# How to change text color when highlighted?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently made a site and ii had change the default highlighted color from blue to tomato red.But some of my text is also tomato red and it make the text difficult to see.How should I change the text color when highlighted?

Comment: Without showing the code you've attempted highlighting anything will be difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using the `::selection` pseudo class:

```
-moz-::selection,::selection{
    color:white;
    background-color:tomato;
}
```

Of course , you can change the colors to your liking. Check out the example here:http://jsfiddle.net/8867H/65/

EDIT: To make it cross compatible , added the selector for firefox also

Comment: isn't it ::selection?

Comment: @MikeYung are u sure , check the link , it works perfectly there

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that works in Firefox too

```
body::-moz-selection { 
color: white;
background: tomato;
}
body::selection { 
color: white;
background: tomato;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    color: white !important;
    background: tomato !important;
}
```

Comment: for highlighted test use text shadow balck or white

Comment: You shall update the explanation in your answer. So the followers can easily understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

for highlighted text use text-shadow like:

```css
.another{
color:tomato;
 text-shadow:1px 2px 3px #858585;
 font-size:16px;
 font-weight:bold;  

}
```

```html
<div class="another">
  lorem ipsum doller sit amit
  </div>
```